# Is it right to use firstly in the middle of a sentence? (In formal writing)

Tags: word-usage

Is it formally accepted to write :

> However,I would like to thank you **firstly** on your.....

Can I use "firstly" in the middle of the sentence?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on why you are using *firstly*. Full context, not a partial sentence would be advisable. But if it uses "firstly...secondly...", *firstly* should be closest to the head of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably always use "first" rather than "firstly".  "Firstly" achieved some currency among people who incorrectly thought they had to use an adverbial form.

"However, first I would like to thank you for your...." (probably not "on your" since we thank *for* things and congratulate *on* things).

Comment: The OED (2nd edition) says: “The word is not in Johnson's Dict. Smart (1846) s.v. First has the note: ‘Some late authors use Firstly for the sake of its more accordant sound with secondly, thirdly, etc.’”